# Есть ли аналог команды chmod в windows 10?

Tags: php, linux, windows, laravel

меня интересует аналог команды "chmod -R 775 ./" на Windows 10. Есть ли таковой аналог? Можете ли вы подсказать, как мне провернуть на Windows то же самое, что делает эта команда в Linux?

Comment: Система прав доступа в винде и юниксах устроена сильно по-разному. Лучше опишите словами, какой результат вы хотите получить, а то фраза "то же самое" довольно размытая

Comment: @andreymal команда "chmod -R 775 ./" дает права на чтение папок и файлов, как я понимаю, так вот мне нужно дать права на чтение в Windows. Сразу скажу, что я знаю, что можно щелкнуть правой кнопкой по той же папке -> свойства -> безопасность и т.д. Я хотел бы узнать, можно ли прописать подобную команду и в Windows.

Comment: И в винде, и большинстве линуксов права на чтение и так есть по умолчанию, и ничего давать не надо. Кому и зачем вы хотите их дать? Кто и когда их отобрал? В общем, что там у вас происходит вообще?)

Comment: Ну а вообще в винде есть [CACLS](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/windows-change-access-permissions-from-the-command-line.html) и [Set-Acl](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-acl?view=powershell-7), но как с помощью них получить «то же самое» это ещё надо думать

Comment: @andreymal, есть такое решение - crater-invoice. Я front-end разработчик, мои знания php стремятся к 0, а там laravel + vite js + vue js. Устанавливается она подобно wordpress в браузере. При этом конечно же нужно прописывать в консоли composer install, создавать .env и т.д., в руководстве говорится, что при установке, нужно прописать "chmod -R 775 ./". После установки сам этот crater работает, но при запуске режима разработки vite, у меня появляется ошибка - "Could not read configuration from PHP" и ничего не работает, соответственно. Я не могу прописать такую же команду на windows.

Comment: С 99% вероятностью ошибка никак не связана с chmod и прописывать этот chmod в винде вообще не надо. Ну и ещё есть вероятность, что если разработчик crater-invoice нигде не упоминает Windows, то скорее всего Windows вообще не поддерживается

Comment: А если в вашем тексте ошибки есть [SyntaxError: Unexpected token W in JSON at position 1](https://github.com/crater-invoice/crater/issues/908), то скорее всего вы просто неправильно настроили PHP

Comment: @andreymal, нет, подобных ошибок нет. Честно Вам скажу, я понятия не имею, с чем это может быть связано, это скорее предположение, что проблема может быть в chmod.